# Eclipse Juno reset

Tags: android

I took Eclipse Juno from a friend, and tried to creating a new android project using that but i am facing problems. Messages appear in the console like below,

```
[2016-02-15 12:32:12 - MyRMS] C:\MyRMS\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. 

[2016-02-15 12:32:12 - MyRMS] C:\MyRMS\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

Also, I see a small red x under the project name after creating it.

Any suggested solution?

Is there any way that i could reset all data from eclipse and start from scratch ?

Comment: On a side note: Start using Android Studio instead of Eclipse.
For your question, have you downloaded the Android Support Library via SDK?

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported for Android development. I wouldn't be surprised to find out that it can't work with the latest support libraries, causing the errors regarding Theme.AppCompat.*

Answer (score 1):

You should move to android studio because eclipse is not supported for android development now. However this issue can be resolved by using different theme for app in styles
try using

```
@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar
```

instead of

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light
```

[image]

or you can add AppCompat library Right clicking on project -> properties -> android -> in the library section , click on add and add appcompat.